# SwiftUI Where exactly to use Lazy Stacks for performance optimization?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack, lazyvstack

A lot of [sites online](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-lazy-load-views-using-lazyvstack-and-lazyhstack) that demonstrate using a Lazy stack to load a lot of views use e.g. `ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { value in` to demonstrate usage.  But in a production app with complex views I can't really find any resources for where and how exactly to use Lazy Stacks.  For example, I have a `MasterView` with many complex views as children (each View contains multiple charts which are expensive to draw).  Should I use Lazy Stacks at the top level as I do below only, or should the subviews (`ComplexView`s) also use Lazy Stacks in them as well?  Or should the subviews use LazyStacks and `MasterView` use a regular VStack?  What would be most optimal from a performance (scrolling standpoint).

```
struct MasterView: View {
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ComplexView()
                    ComplexView()
                    ComplexView()
                    ComplexView()
                    ComplexView()
                    ComplexView() 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ComplexView: View {
    var body: some View {
       VStack { //LazyVStack?? 
            HStack { //LazyHStack?? 
              SwiftUIChart
              Text("Chart Data")
            }
             HStack {
              SwiftUIChart
              Text("Chart Data")
            }
             HStack {
              SwiftUIChart
              Text("Chart Data")
            }
            
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation states that a lazy stack doesn't render the item until it's going to be on screen. If that is useful behavior for you, use it. If not, skip it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack

Comment: @jnpdx yes but do you use Lazy Stacks all the way down to View Hierarchy, that is my question.

Comment: You use them wherever the behavior is beneficial. If you want something lazily-loaded in a stack, use it -- if you don't, you wouldn't use it. In your example above, if you want the chart data lazily loaded once the chart is on the screen, use the lazy stack.